# 'Cannot read property 'listRegistrationsByTag' of undefined' from Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Push.RegisterAsync

Tags: android, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-notificationhub

This is a Xamarin.Forms app running on Android, based on the Azure getting started Mobile App example.

I'm trying to register a device's id for notification services. Originally I was getting unauthorized, so I relaxed authorization settings on the backend. Now I am getting this error and cannot find a reason why.

I checked and double checked that notification hub has the correct Firebase details that align with the app and cannot see what the problem is here, any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you happen to get any resolution on this? I'm experiencing the same thing, even if I just spin up new Mobile/Notification Hubs.

Comment: I'm not a Xamarin expert, but it sounds like the object that is supposed to have `listRegistrationsByTag` method/property is null/not defined. Could you step through the code in debugger and see why it doesn't get initialized? I think doing that will get you closer to resolving the issue.

Comment: This isn't a Xamarin issue, it's an Azure provisioning issue and the Azure team is working on it and should have at least a workaround shortly. Would love to just be able to step through everything on their end, though! That would be awesome! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John,

- If you set WEBSITE_PUSH_ENABLED=false in your appsettings, does the problem go away?
- Can you check your Mobile App's app settings?
  Specifically, I am looking for the existence of the app setting "MS_NotificationHubName". If that app setting doesn't exist, you need to add it, with the name of your notification hub.

Comment: MS_NotificationHubName was not set, however MS_NotificationHubId was set.
Adding MS_NotificationHubName with notification hub name results in correct behavior of RegisterASync

Comment: Here's more infor where the workaround is described as well: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2017/02/23/cannot-read-property-listregistrationsbytag-of-undefined-azure-app-services/

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the Azure App Service Push blade right now.  A fix is being rolled out.  In the interim, instead of using RegisterAsync(), use the method described in the book http://aka.ms/zumobook - chapter 5.

Comment: Adrian, sadly I still get the same "Cannot read property 'listRegistrationsByTag' of undefined" error using the InvokeApi method from CH 5 on all platforms. Crazy thing is this worked great for weeks until last Thursday, and I have provisioned new Mobile Apps/Hubs over and over trying to see if I could get back to something working, but to no avail. Thanks for the possibly tip, though, let me know if you have any other ideas.

Comment: Any idea when the bug will be resolved?
Thanks for the link to the book!